# The jumps of the total variation of a càdlàg function with finite variation.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, bounded-variation

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a [càdlàg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) function with finite total variation, i.e.
$$
V_f(t)\doteq\sup_{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left|f(t_{j,n})-f(t_{j-1,n})\right|<\infty
$$
where $0=t_{0,n}<t_{1,n}<\cdots<t_{n,n}=t$ is any partition of the interval $[0,t]$. I have found the following result:
$$
V_f(t)= V_f(t-)+\left| f(t)-f(t-)\right|\quad (1)
$$
where $f(t-)=\lim_{s\rightarrow t-}f(s)$ indicates the left-limit. The equation $(1)$ says that the jumps of the total variation coincide with those of the function $|f|$.

Any suggestion or reference on where I can find the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any partition of $[0,t]$, $0=t_{0}<\cdots<t_{n}=t$. Let $t_{n-1}<s<t$.
Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})|  & \leq\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|f(t_{i}
)-f(t_{i-1})|+|f(s)-f(t_{n-1})|+|f(t)-f(s)|\\
& \leq V(s)+|f(t)-f(s)|\leq V(t-)+|f(t)-f(s)|.
\end{align*}
Letting $s\rightarrow t^{-}$, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})|\leq V(t-)+|f(t)-f(t-)|.
$$
Taking the supremum over all partitions gives
$$
V(t)\leq V(t-)+|f(t)-f(t-)|.
$$
Conversely, given $\varepsilon>0$, find $\delta>0$ such that
$$
V(t-)\leq V(s)+\varepsilon,\quad|f(t-)-f(s)|\leq\varepsilon
$$
for all $s\in\lbrack t-\delta,t)$. Take any partition of $[0,s]$,
$0=t_{0}<\cdots<t_{n}=s$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})|+|f(t)-f(s)|\leq V(t).
$$
Taking the supremum over all partitions gives
$$
V(s)+|f(t)-f(s)|\leq V(t).
$$
Now for $s\in\lbrack t-\delta,t)$,
$$
V(t-)-2\varepsilon+|f(t-)-f(t)|\leq V(s)+|f(t)-f(s)|\leq V(t),
$$
where we used the fact that
\begin{align*}
|f(t-)-f(t)|  & \leq|f(t-)-f(s)|+|f(t)-f(s)|\\
& \leq|f(t)-f(s)|+\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ gives
$$
V(t-)+|f(t-)-f(t)|\leq V(t),
$$

Comment: I guess here you want to use the fact that the left limit $V(t-)$ exists. I would say that $V(t-)-\varepsilon<V(s)<V(t-)+\varepsilon$ for $s<t$ sufficiently close to $t$. So,  why is it that $V(t-)\leq V(s)+\varepsilon$?

Comment: second: to derive $V(t-)-2\varepsilon+|f(t-)-f(s)|\leq V(s)\leq V(t)$ we need only $V(t-)\leq V(s)+\varepsilon$, $|f(t-)-f(s)|\leq\varepsilon$ and the fact that $V(s)\leq V(t)$ given that $s\leq t$. Hence I do not understand why you say: "where we used the fact that $|f(t)-f(s)|   \leq|f(t)-f(t-)|+|f(t-)-f(s)| \leq|f(t)-f(t-)|+\varepsilon$ "

Comment: The function $V$ is increasing, so the limit $V(t-)$ exists.

Comment: This is clear to me, I do not understand how from $V(t-)-\varepsilon<V(s)<V(t-)+\varepsilon$ you derive $V(t-)\leq V(s)+\varepsilon$.

Comment: From $V(t-)-\epsilon<V(S)$, you add $\epsilon$ to both sides

Comment: Ok, thanks, it was pretty immediate.

Comment: One last comment. How does the inequality $V(t-)+|f(t-)-f(s)|\leq V(t)$ end the proof? Since $V(t)\leq V(t-)+|f(t)-f(t-)|$ is proved, we need to prove $V(t-)+|f(t)-f(t-)|\leq V(t)$, while $V(t-)+|f(t-)-f(s)|\leq V(t)$ only proves that $V(t-)\leq V(t)$ (by taking $s\rightarrow t-$).

Comment: There was a misprint. I fixed it.